# jquery ajax onclick doesn't work

Tags: jquery, onclick, alert

i am trying to get this script work:

```
<script>
    function checkin() {
        var projectId = document.getElementById("projectId").value;
        var userId = document.getElementById("userId").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/includes/ajax.urenKlokken.inc.php',
            data: 'userId=' + userId + '&projectId=' + projectId,
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg) {
                    alert('test');
                    document.getElementById("ChangeKlokinOnSelect").innerHTML = msg;
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

But i don't get a response. When i do this:

```
<script>
    function checkin() {
        alert('test');
    }
</script>
```

i receive the alert. So the link is correct, but something is wrong while loading the AJAX request.

What's going wrong? Does anyone see it?

Comment: do you see request in network tab ? maybe add error callback to see if request is not failing

Comment: It could be anything really. There is nothing obvious wrong with the code, so either your server side code is faulty, the URL is incorrect, there are problems with the DOM interaction, or you are doing something else wrong when you try to call the function. It's impossible for us to say. My advice would be: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: Where are you passing the parameter `msg` ? I don't see it.

Comment: @AshisKumarSahoo: `success: function (msg) {`

Comment: So where does that msg come from? Believe me. It will not work this way. You need to pass parameter to that function. Search for 'parametrs in AJAX function call'

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script may be returning an error meaning that the success callback won't get called. If you're using Chrome I would suggest opening the developer tools and using the network tab to debug the request to `/includes/ajax.urenKlokken.inc.php`.